# Low screen resolution with Intel iRIS Xe - Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: intel-graphics, 21.04

I have a Dell Latitude 3520 and the dreaded Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]. I am using bare installation of Ubuntu 21.04.
Everything (so far) seems to be working fine except the highest resolution is 1366x768. I would prefer to be able to enable 1920x1024 or so.
I am aware it is quite a new card and not fully supported, but I was hoping someone had been able to figure it out.
I have already tried the few suggested posts:

- use `linux-oem-20.04c` --> didn't help
- use `oibaf` updated drivers --> didn't help
- even tried the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` update from Intel website  --> didn't help

Here are the usual command output required (after fresh install):

`lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux linux-work-01 5.11.0-31-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 13:19:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`inxi -G`

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Iris Xe Graphics [1028:0a7c]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Is there something else to do after upgrading the kernel?

Comment: Silly question, but what is the *exact* model number that you have? Reason I ask is because there is a model of the Latitude 3520 that ships with a 1366x768 display. If you have that model, then it cannot give you 1920x1080 with the built-in display.

Comment: You're right @matigo I checked the serial number and the model is indeed 1366x768. It's a new office laptop so I'll have to live with that.

Comment: Office notebooks are the worst. Always the lowest spec, most eyestrain-inducing machines one can possibly receive. I hope you have an external monitor to look at instead.

Comment: I know it was an honest mistake, the model I got is really good (i7 11th gen, 16GB upgraded to 32GB, 512 GB nvme),  if we exclude the resolution. The provider might have taken advantage of us not paying attention to that particular point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some models have limited resolution. I recommend going to Dell support website, enter you serial/tag and check the full specs. If the screen resolution is `1366x768` then that's all you will get.